# How to pass two arguments and their size to a C-function in Matlab?

Tags: c, matlab

I have to call the following C-library function out of Matlab:

```
bool PI_OAD (int ID, const int* channel, const double* pdValueArray, int iArraySize)
```

and the parameter iArraySize should be the size of the arrays channel and pdValueArray.

The parameters channel and pdValueArray are given as follows:

```
pChannel = uint8(channel);
pStep = uint16(step);
```

And my calllib command is:

```
calllib(Controller, 'PI_OAD', ID, pChannel, pStep, int32(24));
```

It doesn't work.

I don't know how to pass the size of the parameters channel and step correctly. Does somebody have an idea?? Thanks!

edit:
Thanks for all the answers, i'll try your suggestions next tuesday when i'm back at work.

Some additional Information:

I need the function PI_OAD to operate a piezo element via a hardware interface, channel is 1 the most time because i have just one axis, and step is the voltage i want to set at the piezo element.

It doesn't work means that i get some errors from the interface. As far as i can remember i get a 'command is to long' followed by an 'unknown command' error.

Comment: pChannel and pStep are pointers, shouldn't you be passing libpointer? like pChannel=libpointer('uint8Ptr',channel); ?

Comment: The matlab manual says that Matlab does the conversion to the right pointertype.

Comment: 1. when you say "it doesn't work" what exactly happens? Segmentation fault? error message? wrong output?
2. According to the function header channel is expected to be int* and pdValueArray should be double*. So, why to you convert `pChannel=uint8(channel)` and `pStep = uint16(step)`? Shouldn't it be `pChannel=int32(channel)` and `pStep = double(step)`?

Comment: Another thing, can you pass the array size as `int32(numel(channel))`?

Comment: I get some error messages from the hardware interface, edited them into the text above. And yes i should convert step into a double, don't know why i choosed int there...

Comment: I don't know the 'numel' function, i'll look it up!

Comment: I should have said that the variables channel and step each just hold one single value, so numel is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your code:

- `channel` is declared as `int *`, while you pass an array of `uint8`
- `pdValueArray` is declared as `double *`, while you pass `uint16`

So passing the size is not your problem - passing the other variables is.

Here is a simple dll I wrote:

```
int PI_OAD (int ID, const int* channel, const double* pdValueArray, int iArraySize){
  int i; 
  mexPrintf("ID %d, size %d\n", ID, iArraySize);
  for(i=0; i<iArraySize; i++)
    mexPrintf("%lf ", pdValueArray[i]);
}
```

Here is how I call it from MATLAB

```
lib = loadlibrary('libtestlib.so','testlib.h');

ID=int32(10);
pChannel = int32([1:10]);
pStep = double([1:10]);
calllib('libtestlib', 'PI_OAD', ID, pChannel, pStep, int32(numel(pChannel)));

unloadlibrary('libtestlib');
```

And here is the output

```
ID 10, size 10
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000 5.000000 6.000000 7.000000 8.000000 9.000000 10.000000
```

All works fine!

Comment: why passing iArraySize as `24`? shouldn't it be `int32(numel(pChannel))`? You get funny numbers in the output after the 10th element! This may lead to access violation and seg fault!

Comment: @Shai oh, sure. you are right. That was a copy-paste from OP code. Changed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a MATLAB MEX-Wrapper, which is a C-function, which will take MATLAB-Defined types (typically mxArray's) and convert them to the right type.

MEX functions aren't that hard to write, see

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating-c-c-and-fortran-programs-to-be-callable-from-matlab-mex-files.html;jsessionid=874554659556527535e9ea9a084c

And:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html

There are a number of examples you can follow in the MATLAB documentation.  Many of them are close to what you want.

Comment: interesting solution, but where's all the fun with `calllib`?